# Можно ли получить SSL-сертификат с поддержкой кириллических доменов?

Tags: ssl, сертификат

Важно, чтобы такой сертификат был доступен для физ-лиц!
Если знаете где такой приобрести, поделитесь ссылкой пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Гуглить в сторону SSL с поддержкой Internationalized Domain Name.

Знаю, что такие сертификаты раньше выдавал Comodo, Symantec. Сейчас, думаю, и другие есть. Letsencrypt тот же.

Comment: В сертификате же в любом случае будет использоваться Punycode. Т.е. можно же руками преобразовать имя домена в punycode и обращаться уже с этим именем в любой CA, который работает с ASCII? Или я не прав?

Comment: @zed я настолько плотно с .рф зоной не работал =/

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять несколько примеров реальных сертификатов, и посмотреть, кто их выдал. Я посмотрел вот эти:

- [наш.дом.рф](https://%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC.%D1%80%D1%84/) - thawte
- [мой-президент.рф](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/) - Let's Encrypt
- [гибдд.рф](https://%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/) - Let's Encrypt
- [жить.рф](https://%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C.%D1%80%D1%84/) - COMODO CA Limited
- [мвд.рф](https://%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84) - DigiCert Inc
- [президентскиегранты.рф](https://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B.%D1%80%D1%84/) - GlobalSign nv-sa
- [безопасныедороги.рф](https://%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/) - GeoTrust Inc.
- [вместеярче.рф](https://%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5.%D1%80%D1%84/) - cPanel, Inc.

Многие другие так же были выданы Let's Encrypt.